# Number of paths in 3D coordinates

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, contest-math

A cute problem which is an extension of a well-known counting problem:

Find the number of paths of length $12$ from $(0,0,0)$ to $(4,4,4)$ passing through adjacent lattice points (for two ajacent points in the path, the distance between them is $1$), which avoid $(1,1,1), (2,2,2), (3,3,3)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use inclusion exclusion. let $f(S)$ be the number of paths that pass through all the elements of $S$. Then we want:

$\color{blue}{f(\emptyset)}-\color{red}{f((1,1,1))}-\color{green}{f((2,2,2))}-\color{purple}{f((3,3,3))}+\color{blue}{f((1,1,1),(2,2,2))}+\color{red}{f((1,1,1),(2,2,2))}+\color{green}{f((1,1,1),(3,3,3))}+\color{purple}{f((1,1,1),(3,3,3))}-\color{blue}{f((1,1,1),(2,2,2),(3,3,3)}$

Calculating each one we get:

$\color{blue}{\binom{12}{4,4,4}}-\color{red}{\binom{3}{1,1,1}\binom{9}{3,3,3}}-\color{green}{\binom{6}{2,2,2}\binom{6}{2,2,2}}-\color{purple}{\binom{9}{3,3,3}\binom{3}{1,1,1}}+\color{grey}{3\binom{3}{1,1,1}\binom{3}{1,1,1}\binom{6}{2,2,2}}-\color{blue}{\binom{3}{1,1,1}\binom{3}{1,1,1}\binom{3}{1,1,1}\binom{3}{1,1,1}}$

Comment: There is a more clever solution... Also you definition of $f(S)$ is unclear.

Comment: What is not clear about $f(S)$? $S$ is a set of points.

Comment: Oops sorry I misread. Includions excluion is not the inteded solution though.

Comment: well, I'm sorry I didn't answer the intended solution. Do you want me to delete it? although I don't see the point in asking a question if you don't want any other solutions.

Comment: No dont delete. your solution is fine. i just asked the question because i think its a nice problem and i want to share with others, and also i want to see some different solutions. in fact i was looking for the mostr streamlined solution (even more than the intended one I have in mind).